# AWS Resources disappearing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am new to AWS so this might just be a settings thing, but some of my resources are not being listed anymore under my admin console.

Specifically, all my DynamoDB tables and Lambda functions are no longer listed on my console. My cloudfront and Route 34 listings are just fine. In addition I no longer see any of my website certifications listed anymore.

I know the resources were not deleted, as I can ping them through other means and get correct responses and such. And I'm listed as the only user and have root access? Why are they no longer showing up?

**Example CLI outputs below** showing that CLI recognizes the tables exist, but none of them show up on my web console anymore. I don't think I changed anything, but I probably did haha.

```
C:\Users\Eric Robertson\Documents\Projects\Personal2\portfolio-site\frontend>aws dynamodb list-tables
{
    "TableNames": [
        "activeGames",
        "fragments",
        "grocery-users",
        "quite-simply",
        "skills",
        "tokens",
        "users"
    ]
}
```

```
C:\Users\Eric Robertson\Documents\Projects\Personal2\portfolio-site\frontend>aws iam list-users
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "UserName": "serverless",
            "UserId": "AIDA3MZR6R3DOFQLU4PYT",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::783399423686:user/serverless",
            "CreateDate": "2020-06-09T19:38:55+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Update: Seems to do with regions being disabled?

[See Updated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfxIo.png)

Comment: Maybe your console is set for different region or you use different account than the CLI is using?

Comment: @Marcin my console is set to global in the upper left corner, the accounts are the same to the best of my knowledge. Is there something specific I should check?

Comment: IAM will be global, but dynamodb is regional. So the question is, which region are your tables in?

Comment: @Marcin That might be it. My tables are in us-east-1, but my regions are all greyed out now? Ill post an updated picture

Comment: Just go to DynamoDB console first, then you will be able to change region. For global services, regions are grayed out, as notion of region does not apply to them.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I am clearly still figuring my way around the console!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was the use of **wrong region** for DynamoDB in the console. When using IAM, all the regions are grayed out since IAM is global service.

To change the region for DynamoDB, first have to go to **DynamoDB console**, and then a change of a region is possible. DynamoDB is a regional service, unlike IAM.